# bokeh This page didn’t load Google Maps correctly

Tags: python, bokeh

When I use bokeh to plot Google Map, it shows this problem "Oops! Something went wrong.This page didn’t load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.". I have used my newest Google Map API, dont know what is going on.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
output_file("gmap.html")
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=30.2861, lng=-97.7394, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)
p = gmap("AIzaSyCEjCcXedjs80NSWbsU2WdURkK7ncG8rYo", map_options, title="Austin")

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(lat=[ 30.29,  30.20,  30.29],
              lon=[-97.70, -97.74, -97.78])
)
p.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=15, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)
show(p)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZIS5.png)

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console for technical details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an [`ApiNotActivatedMapError`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error). This is because you are not using a valid google api key. In the error message you can find a link to an introduction of [how to get an api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

But there is also another option using bokeh with OpenStreetMaps which will give you this nice map with three circles. This will avoid the problem you had.

[image: Openstreetmap of Austin with three circles.]

To make this work you need to use `CARTODBPOSITRON` and `get_provider` from `bokeh.tile_providers`.

### Code

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON, get_provider

output_file("gmap.html")

# helper function for coordinate conversion between lat/lon in decimal degrees to web mercator
def lnglat_to_meters(longitude, latitude):
    """
    Projects the given (longitude, latitude) values into Web Mercator
    coordinates (meters East of Greenwich and meters North of the Equator).
    """
    origin_shift = np.pi * 6378137
    easting = longitude * origin_shift / 180.0
    northing = np.log(np.tan((90 + latitude) * np.pi / 360.0)) * origin_shift / np.pi
    return (easting, northing)

tile_provider = get_provider(CARTODBPOSITRON)

# Lady Bird Lake, Austin Texas
lat = 30.268801
lon = -97.763347

EN = lnglat_to_meters(lon, lat)
dE = 10000 # (m) Easting  plus-and-minus from map center
dN = 5000 # (m) Northing plus-and-minus from map center

x_range = (EN[0]-dE, EN[0]+dE) # (m) Easting  x_lo, x_hi
y_range = (EN[1]-dN, EN[1]+dN) # (m) Northing y_lo, y_hi

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range,
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
p.add_tile(tile_provider)

# circles
source = {'north':[], 'east':[]}
for a, b in zip([-97.70, -97.74, -97.78], [ 30.29,  30.20,  30.29]):
    ans = lnglat_to_meters(a, b)
    source['north'].append(ans[1])
    source['east'].append(ans[0])

source = ColumnDataSource(data=source)
p.circle(x="east", y="north", size=15, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)

show(p)
```

### Comment

The solution above is inspired by the `tile_demo` you can find in the [bokeh github project](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh).